# Unable to mount Iphone

Tags: 10.10, mount, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nothing happens when I connect my Iphone 3G to my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27141/nothing-happens-when-i-connect-my-iphone-3g-to-my-laptop)

I get the following error each time I plug in my Iphone 3gs to usb.

```
Unable to mount (name) iPhone: DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

Anyone else have this error and know of a fix? I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27141/nothing-happens-when-i-connect-my-iphone-3g-to-my-laptop/27163#27163) will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/249/how-can-i-sync-music-with-my-iphone-3g and http://askubuntu.com/questions/27141/nothing-happens-when-i-connect-my-iphone-3g-to-my-laptop

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using ifuse, once installed your iphone will mount when connected:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ifuse
```

then update using update manager under System menu

Now Your iPhone will mount when connected, you can find it under the places menu